# running host is different than the host declared in conf file in ktor

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor

The declared default host in ktor is 0.0.0.0. but when I run my application I see the 127.0.0.1 in the log and It's different than the default host. It is even more strange that when I print the running host manually by environment.config.host, it says the app is running on 0.0.0.0.
I don't know what's going on.

[image]

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman yes

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows OS doesn't route `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` automatically, listening to the `0.0.0.0` address doesn't work correctly. This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/pull/3157/files#diff-3cd4d738423daad8a899f91f379ce86f346944cd61be8dfb13089f3660390d6dR11) by replacing the `0.0.0.0` with `127.0.0.1` on Windows.

Comment: But I need to run my app on 0.0.0.0, I run my code on another computer which uses Windows 10 and It worked correctly. maybe windows 11 have this problem